# How to do OneToOne mapping in JPA with two composite keys in child class and one PK in parent

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, eclipselink

I have a following error stating

> Exception [EclipseLink-7220] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception
>   Description: The @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field
>   specificationSubset] from the entity class [class
>   com.jlr.vista.business.rule.model.Rule] is incomplete. When the source
>   entity class uses a composite primary key, a @JoinColumn must be
>   specified for each join column using the @JoinColumns. Both the name
>   and the referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such
>   @JoinColumn.

I have found many solutions regarding this error but none of them have addressed this kind of issue in every case both classes have same number of composite keys but in my case I have a one PK in entity class and as FK in child class but that child class also has one more PK which makes them composite key.

In this case how should be the `@OneToOne` mapping is achieved ?
I'm using Eclipse link version 2.6

**Rule.java**

```
 public class Rule
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        @Id
        @Column(name="RULE_ID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="RUL_SEQ1")
        @SequenceGenerator(name="_RUL_SEQ1",sequenceName="RUL_SEQ1",allocationSize=1)
        protected Integer ruleId;

        @Column(name="PARENT_RULE_ID")
        protected Integer parentRuleId;

        @Column(name="RULE_TYPE_CODE")
        protected String ruleTypeCode;

        @Column(name="BRAND")
        protected String brand;

        @Column(name="RULE_DESCRIPTION")
        protected String ruleDesscription;

        @Column(name="RULE_REFERENCE")
        protected String ruleReference;

        @Column(name="CONSTRAINT_TYPE")
        protected String constraintType;

        @Column(name="ARCHIVE_STATUS")
        protected String archiveStatus;

        @ManyToMany(targetEntity=VistaRulePartner.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name="RULE_ID", referencedColumnName="RULE_ID")
        })
        protected List<VistaRulePartner> partners;

        @OneToMany(targetEntity=OrderTypeSubset.class,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="RULE_ID", referencedColumnName="RULE_ID",insertable=false,updatable=false)
        protected List orderTypeSubsets;
                    @OneToOne(targetEntity=SpecificationSubset.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,optional=false)
        @JoinColumn(name="RULE_ID",referencedColumnName="RULE_ID",insertable=false,updatable=false, nullable=false)
private SpecificationSubset specificationSubset;
}
```

**SpecificationSubset.java**

```
@IdClass(SpecificationSubsetPK.class)
@Entity
@Table(name="RULE_SPECIFICATION")
@InstantiationCopyPolicy
@Cache( refreshOnlyIfNewer=true,
        coordinationType = CacheCoordinationType.SEND_NEW_OBJECTS_WITH_CHANGES)
public class SpecificationSubset extends ModelArchivable
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="RULE_ID")
    private Integer ruleId;

    @Id
    @Column(name="RULE_SPEC_ID")
    private Integer ruleSpecId = 1;

    @Column(name="SPEC_MARKET")
    private String specMarket;

    @Column(name="DESC_GROUP_ID")
    private String descGroupId;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=FeatureSubset.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="RULE_ID", referencedColumnName="RULE_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="RULE_SPEC_ID", referencedColumnName="RULE_SPEC_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private List featureSubsets;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity=Rule.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="RULE_ID", referencedColumnName="RULE_ID")
    private Rule ruleHolder;
}
```

**FeatureSubset.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RULE_FEATURE")
@NamedQuery(
        name="GetFeatureCodesForVehicleConfig",
        query="SELECT f FROM FeatureSubset f WHERE f.ruleId = :ruleId AND f.featureType = 'YEAR'")
@InstantiationCopyPolicy
@Cache( coordinationType = CacheCoordinationType.SEND_NEW_OBJECTS_WITH_CHANGES)
public class FeatureSubset
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="FEATURE_TYPE_NO")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="VISTA_RUF_SEQ1")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="RUF_SEQ1",sequenceName="RUF_SEQ1",allocationSize=1)
    private Integer featureTypeNo; //Sequence no for the vista_rule_feature table

    @Column(name="RULE_SPEC_ID")
    private Integer ruleSpecId = 1;

    @Column(name="RULE_ID")
    private Integer ruleId;

    @Column(name="FEATURE_TYPE_ID")
    private String featureType;

    @Column(name="FEATURE_CODE")
    private String featureCode;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity=SpecificationSubset.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    /*@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="RULE_ID", referencedColumnName="RULE_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name="RULE_SPEC_ID", referencedColumnName="RULE_SPEC_ID")
    })*/
    private SpecificationSubset specificationSubset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to define mapping information in both sides of relation - one is sufficient, typically it's the owner of association.

So, since your `SpecificationSubset` contains mapping information to `Rule`, in `Rule` you can just reference this relation:

```
@OneToOne(targetEntity=SpecificationSubset.class,
          cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
          fetch=FetchType.LAZY,
          optional=false,
          mappedBy="ruleHolder")  // name of the property in an owning class
private SpecificationSubset specificationSubset;
```

It seems you need to fix owning side as well, for you already have a @Column with `RULE_ID` name:

```
@OneToOne(targetEntity=Rule.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="RULE_ID", referencedColumnName="RULE_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Rule ruleHolder;
```

Comment: @Vladmir ! I didnt understand your second point,can you elaborate please ?

Comment: In `SpecificationSubset` for `List featureSubsets` you define join column as `@JoinColumn(name="RULE_ID", referencedColumnName="RULE_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),`  - it should be defined the same way for the `Rule ruleHolder;`

Comment: Ok ! understood I ll try ur suggestion and ll let you know

Comment: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Multiple writable mappings exist for the field [RULE_FEATURE.RULE_SPEC_ID].  Only one may be defined as writable, all others must be specified read-only.
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping[specificationSubset]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.model.FeatureSubset --> [DatabaseTable(RULE_FEATURE)])

Comment: Got the above error after I followed ur suggestion and also updated question with FeatureSubset class where the mapping with Rule class is commented as you mentioned for SpecificationSubset

Comment: you have to fix the SpecificationSubset - FeatureSubset relation

Comment: In addition to what Vladimir says, these relations are examples of "derived identities". You might take a look at the JPA 2.1 spec, section 2.4.1 "Primary Keys Corresponding to Derived Entities".